# Distributing distinct objects into differently-sized rooms considering an "affinity" value

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Suppose there are $n$ objects that should be distributed into $k$ differently-sized rooms, where the capacity of each room is known. Each pair of objects also have an "affinity" value. The value $A$ is defined as the sum of affinity values for each pair of objects that are placed in the same room, for all rooms. Is there a way to find the maximum $A$ for all permutations?

My first instinct was modeling this as a Pseudo-Boolean Optimization problem. While I'm sure that would eventually work, I was wondering if there is any previous work that could point me to a more efficient method. I tried looking, but I couldn't figure out what to search.

Comment: You might be interested in this related problem: https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2014/11/10/do-you-have-an-uncle-louie-optimal-wedding-seat-assignments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MIP (mixed integer programming). You can search with terms like set membership, set covering or graph coloring
Math model is somewhat like this
Obj $A = \max \sum_k\sum_{(i,j) \in P}a_{i,j}y_{i,j}^k $
where $P =\{(i,j): i,j \in O  \} $ with $O$ being set of your objects with $n = \vert O \vert$

subject to constraints
$ \sum_i x_{i}^k \le c_k \ \ \forall k$

$ \sum_k x_{i}^k = 1 \ \ \forall i$

$y_{i,j}^k \le x_{i}^k $

$y_{i,j}^k \le x_{j}^k \ \ \forall i,j \in P $

$ x_{i}^k+ x_{j}^k \le y_{ij}^k+1 \ \ \forall i,j \in P \  \ \forall k $

where binary decision variable $x_{i}^k = 1$ if object $i$ is assigned to $k$, binary $y_{ij}^k =1 $ if both $i,j$ are assigned to room $k$, parameters $c_k$ is capacity of $k$ while $a_{ij}$ is given affinity between objects $i,j $

Sometimes introducing additional binary variables like $y $ may increase model complexity. In that case you may introduce a continuous nonnegative decision variable $0 \le z$ and replace constraints involving $y$ with pairs of constraints

$ a_{i,j}(x_{i}^k + x_{j}^k-1) \le z_{i,j}^k \le a_{i,j}x_{i}^k$
$ z_{i,j}^k \le a_{ij}x_{j}^k $

Then your objective becomes $\max \sum_k\sum_{i,j}z_{ij}^k $

EDIT: missed a 1 on the RHS as pointed out below

Comment: Your final constraint is missing a $-1$, but this constraint can just be omitted if $a_{ij} \ge 0$.